# The Store View selected for sending Welcome email from is not related to the customer's associated website : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account, multi-website

I have Magento 2.4.4 and multi website is setup in the store. If i create the customer from the front-end then it works fine and correct website assigned to customer also works fine.

Issue is when i try to change website from 'Main Website' to 'My Custom Website' then it throws error like, "The Store View selected for sending Welcome email from is not related to the customer's associated website."

Please check the error and configuration screenshots and let me know how can i fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I came to know that vendor/magento/module-customer/ViewModel/Customer/Store.php this file is updated. If is there any patch can you let me know?

Comment: Something similar happens to me but in my case I see that if in the New Customer form I change the value of the "Associate to Website" field, the "Send Welcome Email From" field stops showing values so you can not select a valid store view. is this your case? [![Image of form that describe a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqx9d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqx9d.png)

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When sending welcome emails in Magento 2, you may encounter an error message that says **"The Store View selected for sending Welcome email from is not related to the customer's associated website."** Here are some possible solutions/checklists:

1. Check that the correct store view is selected for sending the welcome email.
2. Verify that the customer is associated with the correct website and store view.
3. Edit the default welcome email in Magento 2 to match the store view and website associated with the customer.
4. Disable the welcome email in Magento 2 after creating a new customer if it is not necessary.

It is important to ensure that the correct store view and website are associated with the customer when sending welcome emails in Magento 2. You may need to edit the default welcome email or disable it if it is not necessary.